# how to add labels to variables and factors for a final forestplot presentation using forestmodel package in R?

Tags: r, label, r-forestplot

Forest plots using forestmodel package are really nice for multivariate cox regression. However, I have problems to substitute the name of original variables and factors of my dataframe for final presentation labels (i.e variable:age2 for "Age";factors:0 for "<60", 1 for "≥60") .I have sort of limited knowledge of R coding, but I tried expss package to add labels to variables and factors. However, coxph() does not work with labels but factors.

This is my coding:

Cox proportional model:

```
mcox<-coxph(pblsurv~age2+sex1+origin,data = pbl)
```

Forest plot using forestmodel package:

```
print(forest_model(mcox))
```

Variable names in the final plot were age2,sex1,origen; therefore, I used expss package to add labels:

```
pbl <- apply_labels(pbl,
                      age2 = "Age",age2 = c("<60"=0,"≥60"=1),
                      sex1 = "Gender",sex1 = c("Female"=0,"Male"=1),
                      origin = "Ethnicity",origin =c("Non=hispanic"=0, "Hispanic"=1))
```

However, after applying labels coxph did not work:

```
mcox<-coxph(pblsurv~age2+sex1+origin,data = pbl)
Error in coxph(pblsurv ~ age2 + sex1 + origin, data = pbl) : 
  data contains an infinite predictor
```

Any idea what additional code to use in `print(forest_model(mcox))` for a final journal presentation?

Comment: Hi rgeorge, please edit this question to include a minimum reproducible example, so we can cut and paste your data (or a subset of it) and your code into our own R sessions, get the same error as you did, and then work locally to solve the problem so we can share potential solutions. Thanks :)

Comment: @rgeorge This happened with me and after restarting R, it was solved spontaneously.

Answer (score 0):

I have also enjoyed reporting association measurements using the package `forestmodel` and have run into the same problem several times. I searched for solutions and found different ways, but all quite complex, especially for R beginners (which is my case). I found a simple solution to the column name issue using the `var_label` function from the `labelled` package:

```
labelled::var_label(pbl$age2) <- "Age group"
labelled::var_label(pbl$sex1) <- "Gender"
labelled::var_label(pbl$origin) <- "Ethnicity"
```

After that, run forestplot.